# How to determine which size buffer to use when using parBuffer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

The [documentaion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.6/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v:parBuffer) for `parBuffer` says

> `parBuffer :: Int -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]`
>   Like evalBuffer but evaluates the list elements in parallel when pushing them into the buffer."
>
> `evalBuffer :: Int -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]`
>   evalBuffer is a rolling buffer strategy combinator for (lazy) lists.
>   evalBuffer is not as compositional as the type suggests. In fact, it evaluates list elements at least to weak head normal form, disregarding a strategy argument r0."

The first part of my question is does this mean that `parBuffer` also disregard its strategy argument? Also why would it even provide a Strategy argument if it just disregards it?

The second part of my question is how does one determine which size of buffer to use with `parBuffer`? If `parBuffer` always maintains a buffer size of `n`, what is the difference between `n=1` and `n=10` other than more sparks must be kept in memory? I was thinking it might be wise to pick `n=<number of threads>"` but I don't know how that would improve anything because `parBuffer` will still create a spark whenever a spark is consumed, regardless of whether `n=1` or `n=4`.

Answer (score 1):

First answer: `parBuffer` takes a `Strategy` for evaluating *one element* of a list, and gives you back a `Strategy` for evaluating the entire list. So yes, it evaluates the list in parallel. But it still needs to know how to evaluate each item. (Did you want normal form or weak head normal form or...?) So it doesn't *ignore* the first argument.

Second... Benchmark it? I suspect the answer depends on exactly how much work each spark does, how many data dependencies you have, etc.

Comment: wait, then what does this mean? "In fact, it evaluates list elements at least to weak head normal form, disregarding a strategy argument r0"

Comment: I somehow missed that. In that case, either the documentation is wrong, or... yeah, I'm puzzled.

Comment: Reading the source code, it does *look at* the supplied strategy. I think what it's *trying* to say is that you can't evaluate to *less than* WHNF (but presumably *can* evaluate further than that by supplying a suitable strategy).